# jQuery .load() in Hugo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hugo

I'm trying to use jQuery’s AJAX `.load()` method with Hugo pages.

It looks like that in order for `.load()` to work, I need to use plain HTML without any Go markup. But then, I can’t use any Hugo’s functionality…

Here’s a very simple example:
https://github.com/MarciMiller/ajax

- The top two links (Home and Books) .load() just fine, but they don’t
  work as HUGO pages
- The third link (Essays) works as a HUGO page you, but it doesn’t `.load()` with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your baseof.html template.
The jQuery load function does not work because the URL is not properly formatted.

To fix this, you need to remove the single quotes that cause this. This GO markup will be replaced by a string with quotes, so adding extra quotes like you did causes the problem. It may sound counterintuitive and some IDE will throw an error when mixing GO markups inside JS, but that the way it works.

You wrote:

```
$('#home').click(function () {
    $('#content').load('{{"about/index.html" | absURL }}');
});
```

It should be:

```
$('#home').click(function () {
    $('#content').load({{"about/index.html" | absURL }});
});
```